# How to rewrite Wordpress homepage url only?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem and I searched everywhere without being able to find the solution. I tried tweaking htaccess file as well as functions file in wordpress but none has worked.

My problem is the following :

My website is accessible at mywebsite.com . I want my homepage to be accessed via mywebsite.com/home.html and if someone access mywebsite.com he is redirected to mywebsite.com/home.html

How can I do that? I've also disabled cache in case there is a conflict or a certain amount of time before the change appears on website.

I'll be waiting for your answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why anyone would want to do this especially considering that the redirect serves no real purpose.

But to answer your question - create a redirect in your hosting account.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. The redirection would give me a 404 error as the home.html page doesn't exist. I just want to access homepage via home.html via mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I would not modify .htaccess for that.

You can do it simply by adding this code in your theme's **functions.php** :

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_homepage_redirect');

function custom_homepage_redirect()
{
    if (!is_page('home')) // assuming 'home' is the page's slug
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am not trying to redirect to an existing page. I just want the homepage to be mywebsite.com/home.html without home.html existing as a file and redirecting everyone who types mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com/home.html.

Comment: Did you try creating a page 'homepage' and setting it as homepage in Settings > Reading ?